# Python org-mode source block output is always ': None'

Tags: org-mode, python, org-babel

This is my source block:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python
print "hello"
#+END_SRC
```

The output is always:

```
#+RESULTS:
: None
```

This is my org-babel configuration:

```
    (org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages
 '((python . t)
   (C . t)
   (calc . t)
   (latex . t)
   (java . t)
   (ruby . t)
   (scheme . t)
   (sh . t)
   (sqlite . t)
   (js . t)))
```

Python is on my PATH and executable via terminal.

Emacs-lisp SRC blocks works just fine.

Why do I get `None` instead of `hello`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is a peculiarity of how babel handles some languages.  [This](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-python.html) gives some detail on python, and a complete list of options is available [here](https://orgmode.org/manual/Results-of-Evaluation.html#Results-of-Evaluation). There are quite a few useful ones.

Basically, depending on the language, there are several options for output.  Sometimes it makes sense to use the standard output (what `print` does), for other languages (eg octave), it makes sense to display an image.  For python, the default is `value`, which shows the return value of the code, so changing your print statement to a return would give the expected behavior.

This isn't very useful in some cases, so it can be changed by adding `:results output` to the first line of the source block.

Answer (score 24):

In a very simple case like this one, there's a hack I tend to use, replace `print` with `return`:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python
return "hello"
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: hello
```

But in general the better solution will be to use `:results output`, as mentioned by user2699.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results output
print("hello")
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: hello
```

Comment: This is not a hack. :)

Comment: While these examples directly worked, I have also upvoted the @user2699 answer. It is necessary to look to the explanations, not to just repeat a magic. Thanks guys.